# Error in configuration process project files may be invalid

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

i get this error using cmake Version 3.11.2 on Windows 10 with visual Studio 14 2015 created Project. I already used cmake on the same Project on Windows 7 but in Windows 10 it doesnt seem to work.

Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.17134.

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/cmake-3.11.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/Compiler/._ADSP-DetermineCompiler.cmake:1:
  Parse error.  Expected a command name, got bad character with text "".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/cmake-3.11.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/CMakeCompilerIdDetection.cmake:6 (include)
  C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/cmake-3.11.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/CMakeCompilerIdDetection.cmake:32 (_readFile)
  C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/cmake-3.11.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:128 (compiler_id_detection)
  C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/cmake-3.11.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:147 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/cmake-3.11.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:31 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/cmake-3.11.2-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:112 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

See also "C:/Users/Ali/Desktop/Projekt1/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

In the logfile there is nothing useful.Just :The system is: Windows - 10.0.17134 - AMD64

I already checked all other threads on stackoverflow but couldnt find a solution.
Does anyone had the same error or does know what to do to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `Modules/Compiler/` there **shouldn't be files** started with `._`. Probably, you got them when copy CMake from external drive, which has such files as hidden ones. E.g. [from MacOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them).

Either remove files started with `._`, or repeat copying of CMake without them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev's answer! I had never heard of macOS filesystem metadata causing problems.

If you take cmake files on macOS and `tar` it you'll get this. One solution is to use `--disable-copyfile` when you compress it to avoid these files:

```
tar --disable-copyfile -czf cmake-3.19.6-rh6.tgz ./cmake-3.19.6-rh6/
```